# Create iOS Settings App Icon?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, ios

I've searched and searched, but I'm looking to find a tutorial on how to make the outside border of the Settings app icon in iOS. Or the whole icon, I like the effect.

Comment: First google result for "ios settings icon tutorial" is http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/icon-design/how-to-create-a-gearbox-settings-icon-using-simple-shapes/  Have you tried this tutorial?  Granted, it's an Illustrator tutorial, but the steps are fairly similar in photoshop.

Comment: I tried that, I tried every combination of keywords on google, and none of them were what I was looking for

Comment: Can you please update your question with what you have tried already and why it didn't work?  Your question is extremely vague...

Comment: Like the settings app on the iPhone and iPad, I wanna replicate the border around it.

Comment: Post an example image if possible

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/fFSaw.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is a Layer Style stroke to create the border.

Set the stroke to a gradient under Fill Type, pick a good grey and white gradient... then adjust the stroke width to control the size of the border.

[image: gradient border]

Comment: You are the man! That is what i've been looking for, i didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks!